# GCP: kubectl exec/logs fails to container on using UBUNTU as OS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a 2 node cluster with OS as UBUNTU.
After deploying a container, trying a kubectl exec or logs fail with following error :-

```
Error from server: error dialing backend: No SSH tunnels currently open. Were the targets able to accept an ssh-key for user <username>
```

Please tell how to make it work.
Nodes are part of default pool only.
Steps to reproduce:-

```
gcloud container clusters create "gke-test-cluster" --image-type=UBUNTU --machine-type=n1-standard-2  --zone us-east1-c --num-nodes 2 --cluster-version=1.8    
kubectl create -f https://k8s.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/shell-demo.yaml              
kubectl get pod shell-demo          

kubectl exec -it shell-demo -- /bin/bash  
Error from server: error dialing backend: No SSH tunnels currently open. Were the targets able to accept an ssh-key for user "gke-0c"?  

kubectl logs shell-demo  
Error from server: Get https://10.142.0.5:10250/containerLogs/default/shell-demo/nginx: No SSH tunnels currently open. Were the targets able to accept an ssh-key for user "gke-0c"?
```

I am using my laptop for all CLI commands.
This issue has already been raised at:-
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77986235
https://serverfault.com/questions/907468/gcp-kubectl-exec-logs-fails-to-container-on-using-ubuntu-as-os/907882?noredirect=1#comment1177112_907882

Comment: On adding a COS node(using nodepool) to the UBUNTU cluster, exec starts working.  This issue is also reproducible from gcp cloud-shell

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your issue, with your exact commands and it worked just fine. This has to be an issue due to something else (like the firewall, as in the issue tracker is suggested).

Actually, check to confirm you have these three firewall rules:

```
gke-gke-test-cluster-07424324-all ...    
gke-gke-test-cluster-07424324-ssh ...  
gke-gke-test-cluster-07424324-vms ...
```

About cloud shell and your laptop, there is no much difference, if you are correctly authenticated with Cloud SDK. So to say "This issue is also reproducible from gcp cloud-shell" doesn't really make sense.

If you do have the firewall rules, and don't have much done in the project, I would recommend you to create a new project and start over there.

Comment: But for some reason it starts working for me if I add a COS node to same cluster. I have same set of firewall rules created for ubuntu cluster.   
`gke-gke-test-clutter-db979caf-all        default          INGRESS    1000      udp,icmp,esp,ah,sctp,tcp`  
`gke-gke-test-clutter-db979caf-ssh        default          INGRESS    1000      tcp:22`
`gke-gke-test-clutter-db979caf-vms        default          INGRESS    1000      icmp,tcp:1-65535,udp:1-65535`

Comment: This seems to be an issue with my project. It worked in another project. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It was some issue with size of project metadata. We cleaned it up and it worked.